# Men and megaphones (with a lot more)

Tags: logical-deduction

Imagine a grid of infinite size. In each cell can be placed one of three things:

- A man: who will listen for a sound from any direction and pass it to adjacent* men.
- A megaphone: which will take in sound from one end and send it in the other with more amplitude but will still only reach one square.
- A wall: which is an obstacle, but a flow of sound or a megaphone can send sound through it.

> "Adjacent" refers to grid squares that share an edge. Diagonals will not work.

**Examples:**
(`M`=man, `^v<>`=megaphone (in one of 4 directions), `O`=wall)

```
M>OMO>
```

will send a signal from left to right as a flow of sound is created so it can pass through the walls.

```
M>OM
   O
   v
```

is a variation of example 1 in which the "flow" follows a corner pattern.

> "Flow" is an event in which a man that is adjacent to a wall but does not have any men to his sides can pass a sound into that wall. A megaphone can pick up this sound from one of the sides of the wall.

```
MMO>
```

will pass sound through due to flow however

```
MMO>
 M
```

will not as the man next to the wall is not passing the sound into the wall but instead around to the other man next to him.

```
M^M
```

will not send a signal as the megaphone is facing in the wrong direction to accept sound from either man.

```
MOM
```

will not send a signal as there is a wall, but can if there is a flow as shown in the first example.

```
M>OM
  M
```

will pass a signal into the wall and the two men will hear it as it is amplified into the wall by the megaphone.

```
>v
```

will not send a signal. The megaphone cannot receive sound from its side. It receives sound from the open end of the symbol and sends it out the "point" end of the signal.

> **The challenge** is to create an arrangement based on 15 directly adjacent vertical lanes. If a Man makes a sound at the beginning of a lane, the sound must be passed around such that, at the end of the lanes, the sound is in all lanes to the left of the original and itself (e.g. if lane 5 sent a sound, at the end, there would be lanes 1 - 5 with sound but not 6 - 15).
>
> This is possible in 29* tiles length but **what is the shortest distance you can achieve this task in? And what is the layout?**
>
> *Was 31 but I noticed an error (sorry)

To give you a start, here is the 29 tile solution:

```
>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>
>M>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>O>
>>MM>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>
>O>>MM>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>O>
>OMO>>MM>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>
>O>OMO>>MM>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>O>
>OMO>OMO>>MM>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>
>O>OMO>OMO>>MM>OMO>OMO>OMO>O>
>OMO>OMO>OMO>>MM>OMO>OMO>OMO>
>O>OMO>OMO>OMO>>MM>OMO>OMO>O>
>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>>MM>OMO>OMO>
>O>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>>MM>OMO>O>
>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>>MM>OMO>
>O>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>>MM>O>
>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>OMO>>MM>
```

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but can't you just put a single man in lane 1 with a wall to the south of him?  All the zero lanes to the left have a sound at the end, and the rest do not.

Comment: That would work but the challenge is 15 lanes and the required mechanic should work for all lanes

Comment: What is a "flow of sound", exactly? Does a wall essentially act as a man if a megaphone sends sound into it? Also, I assume (given example 4) that two squares sharing only a corner are considered adjacent?

Comment: Does `>v` work?

Comment: @You no. The megaphone will only take in sound from one end and send it out of the other. I will add this as another example

Comment: So this flow event only works when the receiver is a megaphone? So M>OMOM wouldn't reach the rightmost man?

Comment: Can there be space between the lanes?

Comment: @IvoBeckers correct. The "flow" is where megaphes can send sound between two walls via a line of men. A man facing only away from a wall (not to the side) can send sound into the wall for a megaphone to pick up from another side of the wall

Comment: @You no there cannot be space between the lanes

Comment: If there was something that makes noise in silence but makes no noise when there is noise, then we could build a "sound computer" like how there are redstone computers in Minecraft!

Comment: Well noticed. This puzzle is somewhat inspired by the physics of redstone but I was mostly curious as to what response would arise if this kind of challenge was posed in a very different manner to the part of Stack solely for puzzle solvers/creators etc.

Comment: I'm confused. You talk of vertical lanes but the example show horizontal lanes.

Comment: And how exactly does your example prevent the sound to be in the lane itself? As far as I can see can a sound travel just fine to the end of the lane of the lane where the sound started

Comment: Yes there do seem to be quite a few errors in the question. Some may have been me but people have edited this question an awful lot and may have misunderstood parts slightly.

Comment: *You* have edited this question an awful lot. There are only two edits from other people, and both of those were formatting.

Comment: Also, this question is equivalent to [your question on Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261986/).

Comment: @f'' it is and if this is one of the more vague rules that I am not allowed to do so then I'll take this one off no worries.

Comment: You know, you could've just phrased this as a question about Minecraft redstone. No need to try to make up an analogy for it.

Answer (score 4):

I think I go it:

> __________________________`O<M`
>  ________________________`O<M`
>  ______________________`O<M`
>  ____________________`O<M`
>  __________________`O<M`
>  ________________`O<M`
>  ______________`O<M`
>  ____________`O<M`
>  __________`O<M`
>  ________`O<M`
>  ______`O<M`
>  ____`O<M`
>  __`O<M`
>  `O<M`
>  `M`

EDIT: I am not sure how the OP is counting but I believe this is one of the configurations

Comment: This is a working model, however this is the 31 tile solution. Can you find a shorter one?

Comment: @OlieAyre This is 22 Tiles. Unless you count differently

Comment: each lane uses 2 cells length so 2 * 15 makes 30. Then a row of megaphones across them to send out the final signal makes 31

Comment: @OlieAyre nitpicking but I still count 30 since the 15th lane only uses 1 tile not 2

Comment: ok I'll give you that one. Now try and get it below 20.